# Wooden disentanglement puzzle with two metal parts, and a string ended by two wood balls

Tags: mechanical-puzzles

I am convinced this puzzle is not possible, yet it is not easy to prove. It seems, by analogy with another puzzle, that if the board can't pass into a metal ring, it can't be solved.

### Description:

[image: face view]
[image: side view]

- A wooden board with 4 holes in which the wooden balls can't pass
- A string with a wooden ball at each end
- two twisted metal rings in which the wooden balls can't pass

#### Goal:

to remove the metal twisted rings

Comment: Can you turn it enough to get one end of the metal ring stick up through the long slot so that it rotates out?

Comment: @will Yes you can

Comment: Do you know where I can buy this puzzle so I can try it? Online somewhere maybe?

Comment: @JLee I only know it was bought on a market, and wasn't succeeded to find online (#mystery)

Comment: It is "Blaue Schnur" by Jean Claude Constantin, a German puzzle maker. https://www.knobelbox.com/geduldsspiele/jean-claude-constantin/metall-und-schnurpuzzle/6331/blaue-schnur?c=636

Comment: @FlorianF it is totally this one ! I don't understand a word in german, but do you think there is a link to a potential solution of the puzzle?

Comment: "Hinweis: Es wird keine Lösung für dieses Puzzle mitgeliefert."  It says a solution is not provided.  And I feel it is the way it should be.  I will only give a hint: you have to pass one loop over the whole board and over the other loop.